# How do I use pandas to add rows to a data frame based on a date column and number of days column

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to know how to use a start date from a data frame column and have it add rows to the dataframe from the number of days in another column. A new date per day.

Essentially, I am trying to turn this data frame:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
                    'Name':['Peter', 'Peter', 'Peter', 'Peter'],
                    'Planned_Start':['1/1/2019', '1/2/2019', '1/15/2019', '1/2/2019'], 
                    'Duration':[2, 3, 5, 6], 
                    'Hrs':[0.6, 1, 1.2, 0.3]})
```

...into this data frame:

```py
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({
                    'Name':['Peter', 'Peter', 'Peter', 'Peter', 'Peter', 'Peter', 'Peter', 'Peter'],
                    'Date':['1/1/2019', '1/2/2019', '1/2/2019', '1/3/2019', '1/4/2019','1/10/2019', '1/15/2019', '1/16/2019'], 
                    'Hrs':[0.6, 0.6, 1, 1, 1, 1.2, 0.3, 0.3]})
```

I'm new to programming in general and have tried the following:

```py
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': pd.date_range(
    start = df.Planned_Start,
    end = pd.to_timedelta(df.Duration, unit='D'),
    freq = 'D'
    )
})
```

... and ...

```py
df["date"] = df.Planned_Start + timedelta(int(df.Duration))
```

with no luck.

Comment: Can you explain from where do the new rows come?

Comment: @Aryerez want to generate the new rows from adding however many days are in column "Duration".

Comment: @Aryerez That worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not entirely sure what you are trying to achieve as your df_2 looks a bit wrong from what I can see.

If you want the take the duration column as days and add this many dates to a Date column, then the below code achieves that:

You can also drop any columns you don't need with `pd.Series.drop()` method:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
                    'Name':['Peter', 'Peter', 'Peter', 'Peter'],
                    'Planned_Start':['1/1/2019', '1/2/2019', '1/15/2019', '1/2/2019'], 
                    'Duration':[2, 3, 5, 6], 
                    'Hrs':[0.6, 1, 1.2, 0.3]}) 

df_new = pd.DataFrame()
for i, row in df.iterrows():
  for duration in range(row.Duration):
      date = pd.Series([pd.datetime.strptime(row.Planned_Start, '%m/%d/%Y') + timedelta(days=duration)], index=['date'])
      newrow = row.append(date)
      df_new = df_new.append(newrow, ignore_index=True)
```